# Cypher query to take all relationships from one node, and attach them to another node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

My question is.. given two nodes, node A & node B, is there a cypher query that removes all of the relationships from node A and attaches them instead to node B,
so that all nodes that were previously attached to node A, are now attached to node B?

I'm sure there are many use cases for such a query, but my use case is to do with merging multiple social network logins:

Given that I have a member account (member1) using google as a sign in provider
And I have a separate member account (member2) using facebook as a sign in provider
When member1 attempts to connect to the same facebook account that member2 is using as a sign in provider
And member1 requests a merge (merge account)
And member2 confirms the merge
Then the accounts for member1 and member2 will be merged
And one member will be remaining using both google and facebook as a signin provider.

**What is the cypher query to do this?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this thread is old but I googled the same question and didn't found a solution on StackOverflow. So here it is.

As Michael told me [here](https://community.neo4j.com/t/can-i-use-apoc-create-relationships-with-a-relationship-list/1575)
You can use [APOC functions :](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_graph_refactoring_2)

```
apoc.refactor.to(relations, destination_node)
apoc.refactor.from(relations, destination_node)
```

And have something like :

```
MATCH(n2:Resource {name: 'destionation-resource'})
MATCH(n:Resource {name:'source-resource'})<-[r]-()
OPTIONAL MATCH(n)-[r2]->()
CALL apoc.refactor.to(r, n2) YIELD input, output
CALL apoc.refactor.from(r2, n2) YIELD input AS i, output AS o
RETURN *
```

Comment: APOC functions did not exist when I initially asked the question but I think this is the correct answer these days

Answer (score 6):

**EDIT:** there is now way, to specify relationship type dynamically. So, workaround below is limited to relationships with same type and with no properties.

---

Let's create some data:

```
CREATE (n1:Node1)
CREATE (n2:Node2)
CREATE (target1:Target)
CREATE (target2:Target)
CREATE (target3:Target)
CREATE (n1)-[:REL]->(target1)
CREATE (n1)-[:REL]->(target2)
CREATE (n1)-[:REL]->(target3);
```

We have such data right now:

[image: data]

Now we want to "move" relationship from `Node1` to `Node2`

Query:

```
MATCH (n1:Node1)-[r:REL]->(target)
MATCH (n2:Node2)
CREATE (n2)-[:REL]->(target)
DELETE r
```

And result is:

[image: result]

What we basically are done is:

- Get relationship from one path
- Create relationships to other node
- Delete relationships from original node

Comment: Thank you for this. It is very close to what I am looking for. In my case the relationships could be anything, so the data is more like... CREATE (n1:Node1)
CREATE (n2:Node2)
CREATE (target1:Target)
CREATE (target2:Target)
CREATE (target3:Target)
CREATE (n1)-[:REL1]->(target1)
CREATE (n1)-[:REL2]->(target2)
CREATE (n1)-[:REL3]->(target3); I have amended my question to show this more clearly and upvoted your answer.

Comment: My anwser is updated. TL;DR; - there is no possibility to dynamically specify new relationship type.

Comment: Makes me feel less bad for not being able to figure it out, and I learned some cypher out of it in any case. Thanks for the answer. Decided to implement a server side extension as it's trivial to implement this using the java api. Do you know if there is a way to call a server side extension other than via rest? Cypher would be ideal.

Comment: if node 27 have child nodes,how to copy the relationship?

Answer (score 0):

The code for the alternative solution I used is below. I'm having trouble getting the unit tests to run but once they're fixed I'll post a mini project for this on github.

```
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Direction;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Node;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Relationship;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;
import org.neo4j.server.plugins.Description;
import org.neo4j.server.plugins.Name;
import org.neo4j.server.plugins.Parameter;
import org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginTarget;
import org.neo4j.server.plugins.ServerPlugin;
import org.neo4j.server.plugins.Source;

/**
 * @author John Deverall
 * This plugin transfers all relationships from one node to another, including the relationships
 * direction, type and properties. 
 * Can be called from the neo4j browser ui with command
 * :POST /db/data/ext/TransferRelationships/graphdb/transfer_relationships {"sourceNode":"/db/data/node/<node_id>", "destinationNode":"/db/data/node/<node_id>"}
 */
public class TransferRelationships extends ServerPlugin {

    @Name("transfer_relationships")
    @Description("Transfer all relationships from one node to another")

    @PluginTarget(GraphDatabaseService.class)
    public Long transferNodes(@Source GraphDatabaseService graphDb,
            @Description("The source node") @Parameter(name = "sourceNode", optional = false) Node sourceNode,
            @Description("The destination node") @Parameter(name = "destinationNode", optional = false) Node destinationNode) {

        try (Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx()) {
            // transfer outgoing relationships
            Iterable<Relationship> outgoingRelationships = sourceNode.getRelationships(Direction.OUTGOING);
            for (Relationship relationship : outgoingRelationships) {
                Node otherNode = relationship.getOtherNode(sourceNode);
                Relationship newRelationship = destinationNode.createRelationshipTo(otherNode, relationship.getType());

                Iterable<String> propertyKeys = relationship.getPropertyKeys();
                for (String key : propertyKeys) { 
                    Object property = relationship.getProperty(key);
                    newRelationship.setProperty(key, property);
                }

                relationship.delete();
            }

            // transfer incoming relationships
            Iterable<Relationship> incomingRelationships = sourceNode.getRelationships(Direction.INCOMING);
            for (Relationship relationship : incomingRelationships) {
                Node otherNode = relationship.getOtherNode(sourceNode);
                Relationship newRelationship = otherNode.createRelationshipTo(destinationNode, relationship.getType());

                Iterable<String> propertyKeys = relationship.getPropertyKeys();
                for (String key : propertyKeys) { 
                    Object property = relationship.getProperty(key);
                    newRelationship.setProperty(key, property);
                }

                relationship.delete();
            }
            tx.success();
        }
        return destinationNode.getId();
    }
}
```