# combine two nodes with cypher,and make the relationship point to the same one

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In my database i have two nodes , that are very Similar.  difference of property :lat and lng between two nodes are very small .
I want to combine two nodes as one node. and make all relationship link to that node.

the following are two nodes (propertys)

```
node1 {name:'railway station',lat:36.699,lng:119.1}
node2 {name:'railway station',lat:36.7,lng:119.099}
```

How to do it with cypher? i think it should have 'where' statement like:

```
WHERE ABS(node1.lat-node2.lat)<0.001 and ABS(node1.lng-node2.lng)<0.001
```

Comment: Are the nodes connected in any way by relationships?  If not, you'll be doing pairwise combination of every set of two nodes in the DB which will be slow.

Comment: Which node is the "winner"?  I.e. should node1 or node2 be kept in your example?

Comment: Do the relationships that you're copying have any attriubutes/properties on them?   If not, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27984668/move-copy-all-relationships-to-different-node

Comment: i want to delete node2 , make all relationship that link to node2  relink to node1